# How to make Ranking based on Year and Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking, dense-rank

I am trying to put Rank based on Year and Month. I have records like

**Products**

```
ProdID  Years  Months  Quantity
--------------------------------
1652    2018    10         2    
1010    2018    9          2    
2236    2018    10         2    
2236    2018    10         2    
1445    2019    5          2    
1789    2019    12         2    
1232    2018    12         2
```

I tried the below Query

```
SELECT
    ProdID, Years, Months, Quantity,
    DENSE_RANK()OVER (Partition By Years Order By Months) Ranks
FROM Products
```

Obviously, the result will be

```
ProdID  Years  Months  Quantity   Ranks
---------------------------------------
1010    2018    9          2       1
1652    2018    10         2       2 
2236    2018    10         2       2
2236    2018    10         2       2
1232    2018    12         2       3
1445    2019    5          2       1
1789    2019    12         2       2
```

**Expect**

```
ProdID  Years  Months  Quantity   Ranks
---------------------------------------
1010    2018    9          2       1
1652    2018    10         2       2 
2236    2018    10         2       2
2236    2018    10         2       2
1232    2018    12         2       3
1232    2018    12         2       3
1445    2019    5          2       4
1789    2019    12         2       5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the partition by clause from your query. Just use order by clause.

```
SELECT ProdID, Years, Months, Quantity,
DENSE_RANK()OVER (Order By Years, Months) Ranks
FROM Products
```

Comment: Correct bro. 5 min left to accept your answer. Thank yhou

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    ProdID, Years, Months, Quantity,
    DENSE_RANK()OVER (ORDER BY  CAST(CAST(MONTHS AS VARCHAR)+'-01-'+CAST(YEARS AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)) Ranks
FROM Products
```